# Determine the values of q for which the equation Ax=b is consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is given below:

[image]

Below is my solution, the problem is that it dose't match the solution.

[image]

Can someone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Hint: if $q=0$ the matrix is singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not perform row reduction correctly: the values under each pivot must be $0$. So at the second step you should have obtained
:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&0\\
0&-2&-3&1\\
0&-2&q-3&2
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&0\\
0&2& 3&-1\\
0&0&q &1
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&0\\
0&-2&-3&1\\
0&-2&q-3&2
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&0\\
0&2& 3&-1\\
0&0&q &1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Now if $q=0$, the system is inconsistent. If $q\neq 0$, we can continue row reduction upwards:
\begin{align*}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&0\\
0&2& 3&-1\\
0&0& 1 & \dfrac1q
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&-\dfrac1q\\
0&2& 0&-1-\dfrac3q\\
0&0& 1 & \dfrac1q
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&-\dfrac1q\\
0&1& 0&-\dfrac{q+3}{2q}\\
0&0& 1 & \dfrac1q
\end{bmatrix}\\
\rightsquigarrow
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&\color{red}{\dfrac{q+1}{2q}}\\
0&1& 0&\color{red}{-\dfrac{q+3}{2q}}\\
0&0& 1 & \color{red}{\dfrac1q}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you please write the formula you use after the first step. If I did not perform row reduction correctly.

Comment: I did $R_2\leftarrow R_2-4R_1$ and simultaneously $R_3\leftarrow R_3-3R_1$. At the following step,  $R2\leftarrow -R_2$, then $R_3\leftarrow R_3+ R_2$. Does that make it clearer to you?

Comment: It dose thank you very much for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the first two rows are linearly independent and subtracting the second and third rows from the first in the system $Ax=b$ you have $-qz=-1$. So if $q=0$ we have $0=-1$ and the system is inconsistent. For all the other values $q \ne 0$ the system is consistent.